# Chapter Heading on own page

Tags: formatting, pdftex, chapters

My University has only provided a word template for my thesis and I am required to try to adapt the LaTeX style as close as possible to the template. I'm having a bit of trouble with the Chapter heading formatting. It would need to look as close as possible to the image: with the text centered on the page horizontally and vertically, the number bigger than the chapter name and without the word "Chapter". Also important that it doesn't affect the tiles of the table of contents, list of figures etc as those are different.

I would provide MWE, but I'm not sure it's relevant in this case.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Chapter heading]

Comment: Welcome. I think you should use `\part`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A MWE would help here, since we don't know your preferred document class (and a solution for memoir could be radically different than one for report or book).

Answer (score 2):

You can have this, using `titlesec`. Note you'll have to design another formatting for the table of contents, abstract, list of figures, &c., for wich auch a design wouldn't be relevant.

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, twoside]{report}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newlinetospace]{titlesec}%


\usepackage{microtype}
 \SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\fontsize{32pt}{48pt}\bfseries\sffamily\filcenter}{%
\fontsize{72pt}{72pt}\selectfont\scalebox{1.4}[1]{\thechapter}}{0.67em}{\lsstyle}[\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{40ex}{40ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Descripción de\\los estilos del texto}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. In terms of the formatting the Table of Contents, List of figures etc so that they look as before (standard formatting, before applying this chapter style), how would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: You have two solutions: either you define another formatting for unnumbered chapters, that reproduce the previous  look, with `\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{…}`, or you the code for `\titleformat{\chapter}{…}` in the `body` of the document, within a group.

Comment: I have put the code you gave me inside the \mainmatter and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks!